# Installation .Net 1.1. on 64-bit win 7

Tags: .net, iis

I installed .Net 1.1. on a Win 7 (which already had .NET 4 installed). Afterwards, I started getting the following error:

> Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll"

I need help please. Is there anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: That looks like *part* of an error message. Can we have the whole thing please?

Comment: I had this issue after installing .NET 1.1 on my machine. Whole message : HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
Calling LoadLibraryEx on ISAPI filter “c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_filter.dll” failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered same problem in my PC. 
To configure your Application Pool, open the Application Pool in IIS Manager bring up Advanced Options and Enable 32 Bit.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this today after installing .NET 1.1 (don't ask :P ).

For me this was the resolution:

1. Open Internet Information Services
2. Click on the computer name Open
3. ISAPI Filters Correct ASP.NET_4.0_32bit executable path to not
   include a double '\'.

In my case it was set to:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\\aspnet_filter.dll
```